# Sort array of file paths by distance relative to path of file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a list of file paths which I would like to sort by closest to the current file path.

So far I have this:

```
filePaths
    .sort((a, b) => {
      const relativeA = path.relative(currentFilePath, a);
      const relativeB = path.relative(currentFilePath, b);
      const countOfBacksA = (relativeA.match(/\.\.\//g) || []).length;
      const countOfBacksB = (relativeB.match(/\.\.\//g) || []).length;
      return countOfBacksA - countOfBacksB;
    })
```

which seems to work ok but also seems really slow (I have a list of 15,000 files). Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: do you have an example wit data and wanted result?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Possibly a question for codereview or algorithms

Comment: What is your definition of “closest”? You appear to be counting the occurrence of `../` in the relative paths – but would `foo/bar.txt` not be a lot closer to currentFilePath, than say `../../../../baz.txt`? If you only need to look into the one direction for some reason, then your question should mention that.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah I could use some help with the closest functionality. I am not sure the best way to do that so that was my naive approach. I am not sure i understand your example though. foo/bar.txt is not a relative path.

Comment: _“foo/bar.txt is not a relative path”_ - uhm, yes, of course it is. If you are currently in the directory `/abc/xyz/`, and you combine that with the relative path `foo/bar.txt`, you’ll end up with `/abc/xyz/foo/bar.txt`. It might be that you only need to handle paths that go _above_ the current directory, not below it, in your specific use case (that was kinda the point of my remark, asking for clarification on that) - but that doesn’t mean that only the former would classify as “relative paths” to begin with.

Comment: ok i see. I think that would come through as `./foo/bar.txt` in my function but yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are calculating relative path, countOfBackspace everytime. You can use a lookup table to store the relativePath and countOfBackspace when you calculate for the first time.

Like the following,

```
lookUpObj = {};
filePaths
    .sort((a, b) => {
      const relativeA = path.relative(currentFilePath, a);
      const relativeB = path.relative(currentFilePath, b);
      if(!lookUpObj[relativeA]) {
         const countOfBacksA = (relativeA.match(/\.\.\//g) || []).length;
         lookUpObj[relativeA][countOfBacks] = countOfBacksA;
      }
      if(!lookUpObj[relativeB]) {
         const countOfBacksB = (relativeB.match(/\.\.\//g) || []).length;
         lookUpObj[relativeB][countOfBacks] = countOfBacksB;
      }
      return lookUpObj[relativeA].countOfBacks - lookUpObj[relativeB].countOfBacks;
    })
```

This is one optimization I can suggest you from the top of my head.

Comment: You are still calculating the relative path every time here. Why not do that only once as well? The currentFilePath does not change, so `path.relative(currentFilePath, a)` should not change either, when that same `a` element gets passed in for comparison a second time.

Comment: You could skip the `path.relative(currentFilePath, a)` calculations as well. You could use a `Map` object as a lookup if `a` and `b` are objects. But, OP has not shared any input

Comment: This definitely helps a lot. I used a map for the relative calc and the count and it just about halves the time for running on 15000. from 180 -> 90 ms